# Crash when using TableviewController

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to use a TableViewController but it makes me crazy because I really don't understand my code crashes in one project but not the other.

The same code (copy-pasted) to different XCode project runs successfully.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var listeDeListes = [AnyObject]()
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.addItem))

        if (NSUserdefault.standartDefault.objectForKey("identity") != nil) {
            listeDeListes = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("identity")!
        }  
    }

    func addItem() {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "New Resolution", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: ({
            (_) in

            if let field = alertController.textFields![0] as? UITextField {

                self.saveItem(field.text!)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }))

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler ({
            (textField) in

            textField.placeholder = "Type smothing..."

        })

        alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func saveItem(itemToSave: String) {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        //defaults.setInteger(identity, forKey: "identity")

        listeDeListes = listeDeListes + [itemToSave]
       defaults.setObject(listeDeListes, forKey: "identity")
        defaults.synchronize()

    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listeDeListes.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")! as UITableViewCell

        let item = listeDeListes[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = item as! String

        return cell
    }
```

This code works and does't work at the same time. Please help me to find why and how.

In the the "bad" project" I get this error message:
[image]

Comment: How are you setting up the table view? Via Storyboards or programmatically? Either way the cell needs to be registered with the same reuse identifier.

Comment: Nothing in the storyboard. I just set the class to the tableView in the storyboard. Nothing more

Comment: `run successfully and crash.` a bit contradictory don't you think.

Comment: That's Why it make me crazy :) i want to take it in my application but it don't work inside. But my test, so just this, work without problem. I don't understand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the cell with the same identifier.

Since you're using storyboard to setup your table, in your storyboard select the cell inside your TableViewController then open the Attributes Inspector (⌥⌘4) and write `Cell` in front of Identifier.

Comment: Thanks ! I just have to set it on storyboard. I can't believe i waste a lot of time for this because the answer is so simple...

Answer (score 1):

it's probably because you did not set a Reuse Identifier via Storyboard for your table view's Prototype cells.

Could you also try changing your cell code to

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
```

Comment: Thank you @meowmeowmeow, i set it on storyboard and it work :-)